# certificate verify failed Telegram

Tags: php, ssl, telegram-bot, telegram

Доброго времени суток. Возникла потребность в написании телеграм-бота с использованием WebHook. Имеется самоподписанный сертификат от Let's Encrypt. Отправляю через CURL сертификат формата *.pem, при повторном запросе "getWebhookInfo" выводит следующую ошибку:

```
    SSL error {337047686, error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed}
```

Сертификат был верифицирован как "Сертификат сервера SSL".

Массив с сертификатом отправляется - 100%.
Пробовал ставить сгенерированный сертификат - так же возвращает ошибку.
Может необходимо отправлять не "Сертификат сервера SSL"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень распространенная ошибка, в данном случае вы кидаете сертификат телеграму, но он думает что данный сертификат верифицирован и ожидает полной проверки. Решение очень простое в **curl** запросе перед сертификатом поставьте знак @ 
Это будет означать что сертификат самоподписаный (я понимаю что let's encrypt не самоподписаный, но в данном случае мне кажется полная проверка сертификата и не нужна, телеграмму шифрует - вы расшифровуете, все просто)
Должно получится так:

```
curl -F "url=https://ваш айпи или доменное имя:порт/" -F "certificate=@путь к сертификату(ну или перейдите в папку где он лежит и можно просто указать имя)" "https://api.telegram.org/botТОКЕНБОТА/setwebhook"
```

Если хотите "живой пример ))" :

```
curl -F "url=https://177.177.177.77:443/" -F "certificate=@tele.pem" "https://api.telegram.org/bot321321321:dsad1k3j2b3jj321h/setwebhook"
```

Comment: Все верно, сертификат не подписанный и отправлять им не было смысла, жаль, что telegram не возвращает результат, типа "Сертификация пройдена". В любом случае спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 0):

Если необходимо просто установить webhook то перейди по ссылке, подставив нужные значения https://api.telegram.org/botXXXXXXXXX:YOUR_TOKEN/setWebHook?url=YOUR_URL
С сертификатами от lets encrypt и вебхуками у меня проблем не возникало

Comment: Благодарю, в документации написано, мол следует отправить сертификат, но, к сожалению, телеграм не отправляет результат, что сертификат не требуется. Спасибо Вам за ответ.